How to add a color-coded line with extra information
I intend to make a plot of Suspension Travel x Distance of a train. I have a dataset with these information and with information relating if the train is in a straight track or in a curve. I want to mimic the following image, but I have some additional information I have to add (bridge location and tunnel for example). The problem is that what I tried takes almost four minutes to run.
Plot I want to copy

# Plot of the line I want to add
def transition_line(xmin, xmax):
    for i in range((df_irv['Distance'] - xmin).abs().idxmin(), (df_irv['Distance'] - xmax).abs().idxmin()):
        plt.plot([df_irv['Distance'][i], df_irv['Distance'][i+1]], [max(df_irv['SuspTravel']) + 0.5]*2, color='red' if df_irv['Element'][i] == 'CURVA' else 'blue', linewidth=10, alpha=0.5)

# Function to plot the data with adjustable x-axis limits
def plot_graph(xmin, xmax, sensors):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    plt.plot(df_irv['Distance'], df_irv[sensors], label='Suspension Sensor')
    plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
    plt.xlabel('Distance (Km)')
    plt.ylabel('Suspension Sensor')
    plt.title('Suspension Sensor vs Distance')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)
    transition_line(xmin, xmax)
    plt.show()

# Create sliders for x-axis limits
xmin_slider = IntSlider(value=0, min=0, max=df_irv['Distance'].max(), step=1, description='X min')
xmax_slider = IntSlider(value=20, min=0, max=df_irv['Distance'].max(), step=1, description='X max')

# Interactive plot
interact(plot_graph, xmin=xmin_slider, xmax=xmax_slider, sensors = ['SuspTravel', 'Roll', 'Bounce'])

Image produced by my attempt


maybe reduce data - don't display everything but every second element, or every tenth element.

I did try it, but it still takes too much time. And if I use the minimum resolution for the distance the analysis will be futile.

if it is too slow then it may need to use different language instead of Python.

Calling plt.plot() many times in a loop can be slow. (Also, calculating the same max(df_irv['SuspTravel']) for each step in the loop can be avoided by calculating it once before the start of the loop.)
To speed up the drawing of the short lines, a similar approach can be used as in multicolored lines code from matplotlib's tutorial. Instead of a loop, numpy's arrays are much faster (arrays are implemented in optimized C code).
Here is how the code could look like:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create some dummy test data
df_irv = pd.DataFrame({'Distance': np.random.randint(10, 100, 1000).cumsum(),
                       'SuspTravel': np.random.randn(1000).cumsum() * 100,
                       'Element': np.random.choice(['CURVA', 'RECTA'], 1000, p=[.1, .9])})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# add plot
ax.plot('Distance', 'SuspTravel', data=df_irv)

# add "transition line"
xmin = df_irv['Distance'].min()
xmax = df_irv['Distance'].max()

id_xmin = (df_irv['Distance'] - xmin).abs().idxmin()
id_xmax = (df_irv['Distance'] - xmax).abs().idxmin()
xvals = df_irv['Distance'][id_xmin:id_xmax + 1]
yvals = np.full(id_xmax - id_xmin, max(df_irv['SuspTravel']) + 0.5)
colors = df_irv['Element'][id_xmin:id_xmax].map({'CURVA': 'red', 'RECTA': 'blue'})

segments = np.c_[xvals[:-1], yvals, xvals[1:], yvals].reshape(-1, 2, 2)
lines = LineCollection(segments, colors=colors)
lines.set_linewidth(10)
line = ax.add_collection(lines)
plt.show()



Thanks, I will try it and return with a feedback.
